# How do I track who add/edit the current information

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have several tables like as attendance, fee, salary, leave etc.

In this system has more than one admin,subadmin etc.

I need to keep a track who add new information and who edit the current data, also I have to keep previous data.

How could I design my database for tracking this database. My plan is given below:

```
       For adding track:
             AddBy(id(row id of adding information),table_name,adder).

       For editing track:
            editBy(id(row id of adding information),table_name,field_Name,previousData,editor)
```

Is it sufficient for tracking one and which data is changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think Different's answer is better. But you can change this as:

```
 id | table_name | operation |previous_data(with fields)| user_id | ch_time
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 1    fee_table    INSERT    id:120,fee:250    1      2014-04-13 09:10:53
 2    fee_table    UPDATE    id:10,fee:50      2      2014-04-16 09:10:53
 3    fee_table    DELETE    id:120,fee:250    1      2014-04-18 09:10:53
```

For storing data use your mvc serialized data. Use php serialize() and unserialize() function.
As:
$sqldata = array (serialize($session_data), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);

Comment: May be this is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table named `operation_logs` like:

```
id | table_name | table_pk | operation | used_id | log_time
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1   fee_table      5         INSERT       1        2014-04-15 09:10:53
 2   fee_table      9         UPDATE       2        2014-04-16 09:10:53
 3   fee_table      5         DELETE       1        2014-04-17 09:10:53
```

Something like that

Comment: ,Good answer.But there is lack of sufficient information.
Where is my previous data that is changed ?*

Comment: Well if you are using MVC then you can save the current model in a field as serialized array (That is what I have done using Yii). Or query data for the primary key in a object before Updating or deleting it and then convert it to serialized array or JSON and store in a new column e.g `data_snapshot`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the scenario you´re basically looking for a trigger.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

A trigger is a routine that is invoked whenever an operation (one of those given in the trigger definition) is performed on a table row.
The trigger function would be a stored procedure that - in your case - stores the old content of the row (in case of an update) to a log table.

If it comes to data being inserted I´d just add columns like "created_by" (default to the current user name) and created_time (default to current_timestamp).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it store my previous data according to my question or is it possible using triggering ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column in your desired table named 'userID'. In general practice whenever a user is logged on then that particular user's data can be retrieved and stored in an object. or user's Id can be stored in a session variable directly or from that object.

After that, save that user's id from the session during each 'Add' or 'Edit' Operation. In this way you will be able to keep track whoever did which operation.

Additional columns of the table may be: operation type, operation time. Or you can use a global table with another additional column named 'table name', if you do not want individual table for each task.

Thanks

Comment: Please read my question again.Your first idea is well, But I need to track the previous data for restore or this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a technique for this,Any body can modify or suggest me. I will keep my data into a table using php serialize function. Create a table named history like as

```
 history(id,target_table(name of the table), target_id (ID of the saved entry),create/edit/change data (serialized data of the saved row),date)
```

All of data that is changed or edit or delete, all of these are kept into this table using serialize and when need these data, I will make them unserialize.